# Redis Cluster Support in Redis 2.8.19

Tags: redis, cluster-computing

I just started evaluating Redis. I am using Redis 2.8.19 which the most latest stable release. Redis 2.9 is still unstable and Redis 3.0 is just available for developer's preview (not recommended for production). I was tryin to setus a cluster of Redis and when I changed my redis.conf and appended

cluster-enabled yes
cluster-config-file nodes.conf
cluster-node-timeout 5000

and started my Redis server by 
src/redis-server ./redis.conf

it gave me an error as follows

*** FATAL CONFIG FILE ERROR ***
Reading the configuration file, at line 2

> > > 'cluster-enabled yes'
> > >       Bad directive or wrong number of arguments

I googled the error and got to know that my version (2.8.19) does not support cluster. I was still unable to fine any such specification in Redis Docs. My question is simple. Does Redis 2.8.19 supports redis cluster configuration? Or I have to upgrade to Redis 2.9 or Redis 3.0. I am evaluating Redis because I need to deploy it in production. Please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis Cluster support is only for versions >= 3.0.0. Redis 3.0.0 will be released as a stable version in a matter of days, it's a good idea to use it if you want to use Cluster. The cluster support is considered to be stable, however for it to be considered *mature* we want to see adoption. Btw there is already at least a *very* large site using it in production. Currently the most sane thing to do if you need Redis Cluster is to test it for your use case, and if it looks great, use it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I am using Redis 3.0.0. Now my requirement is like this. I want to perform mass insertion into my cluster. When using single instance, I was able to use jedis pipeline. But I am also aware that pipeline is not supported in Redis Cluster "yet". So, how am I supposed to perform mass insertion in redis cluster.

Comment: You can use pipelining with Redis Cluster for mass inserts, however you need to make sure to send the right part of the key space to each different node (depending on the hash slots), and, to avoid resharding the cluster while doing mass inserts of course.

Answer (score 1):

Redis cluster is supported only in Redis 3.0+ (which is now stable). I have written a simple API called "Simple Redis Cluster Client" which can be used in redis's sub 3.0 versions for running in a cluster like mode (Not precisely a cluster, it just distributes keys among redis nodes based on the key's hashcode, You can have a look @ https://github.com/prash-mi/simple-redis-cluster-client

Comment: We are actually using Redis Cluster in production and it works like a charm. I am using JedisCluster java API for Redis Cluster interactions. My RedisDAL looks similar to your PooledConnection but with less configuration settings.

Answer (score 0):

Cluster support for Redis is **only** from v3 - v2.8.19 doesn't do clustering.